# How to create a new child in firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to crate a NEW child of my node in firebase using this code:

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child((FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)!).child("following").setValue([ViewController.usersUid[currentUser]:"true"])
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child(ViewController.usersUid[currentUser]).child("followers").setValue([(FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)! : "true"])
```

And each child creates correctly in my DB, but i have an error:

[image]

on this string:

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child((FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)!).child("following").setValue([ViewController.usersUid[currentUser]:"true"])
```

I have no idea what means this error (console says nothing) and how I could fix it. Please help me to handle with it. Thanks in advance.

> - thread #1: tid = 0x20d86, 0x0000000100de1c78 libdispatch.dylib`dispatch_group_leave + 76, queue =
>     'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1,
>     subcode=0x100de1c78)   * frame #0: 0x0000000100de1c78
>     libdispatch.dylib`dispatch_group_leave + 76
>     frame #1: 0x0000000100027498 Elite Club`thunk + 68 at ViewController.swift:0
>     frame #2: 0x00000001001438a4 Elite Club`**43-[FValueEventRegistration
>     fireEvent:queue:]_block_invoke.57((null)=) + 88 at
>     FValueEventRegistration.m:60 [opt]
>     frame #3: 0x0000000100ddd258 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
>     frame #4: 0x0000000100ddd218 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 16
>     frame #5: 0x0000000100de2280 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1200
>     frame #6: 0x0000000184386810 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE** + 12
>     frame #7: 0x00000001843843fc CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1660
>     frame #8: 0x00000001842b22b8 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
>     frame #9: 0x0000000185d66198 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 180
>     frame #10: 0x000000018a2f97fc UIKit`-[UIApplication _run] + 684
>     frame #11: 0x000000018a2f4534 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 208
>     frame #12: 0x0000000100044258 Elite Club`main + 140 at AppDelegate.swift:15
>     frame #13: 0x00000001832955b8 libdyld.dylib`start + 4

UPDATE: solution in my answer: [dispatch_group_leave error while adding new child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43304034/dispatch-group-leave-error-while-adding-new-child/43318608#43318608)

Comment: Break your code into smaller expressions/lines so you can find which line is triggering this error.

Comment: Instead of adding screenshots of the error, please add the actual error to the question. To capture the error message, right click on the red indicator and "Reveal in Issue Navigator".

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen van Puffelen, enqueued from com.apple.main-thread

Comment: in console: (lldb)